# How can I search GNU info pages with Dash?

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, info, yelp

There is a scope for searching manual pages but I fail to find a scope for searching GNU info pages.  I can launch `{ yelp 'info:coreutils'; }` from the command line but not from the Dash.